# Search in database with Spring JPA

Tags: spring-boot

I have 3 classes like this, each of them is a table in a corresponding database. Please ignore the comment, and every one of them has getters and setters.

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Plate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id; //plate id
    
    @Column
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String name; // tên món
    
    @Column
    private double price; //giá bán
    
    @Column
    private String intro; //giới thiệu
    
    @Column 
    private String howTo = ""; //cách làm
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    Type type;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "plate")
    @JsonManagedReference
    Set<Recipe> recipes;
}

@Table
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id; //công thức id
    
    @Column
    private int quantity; //số lượng
    
    @Column
    @Size(max = 10)
    private String unit; //đơn vị
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "plate_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    Plate plate;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    Ingredient ingredient;
}

@Table
@Entity
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id; //id nguyên liệu
    
    @Column
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String name; //tên nguyên liệu
    
    @Column
    private String note; //ghi chú
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredient", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    Set<Recipe> recipes;
}
```

My repositories only extend JpaRepository.
I want to build a method that searches a plate by its ingredient(s).
Currently, I have this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/plate")
public class PlateController {

    @Autowired
    PlateRepository plateRep;
    @Autowired
    TypeRepository typeRep;
    @Autowired
    IngredientRepository ingreRep;
    @Autowired
    RecipeRepository recipeRep;

    @GetMapping(value = "/findbyingredient")
    public List<Plate> findPlateByIngredient(@RequestParam(required = false) String ingredient) {
        List<Plate> results = new ArrayList<Plate>();

        List<Recipe> listRecipe = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
        for (Recipe recipe : recipeRep.findAll()) {
            if (recipe.getIngredient().getName().toLowerCase().contains(ingredient.toLowerCase())) {
                listRecipe.add(recipe);
            }
        }

        if (listRecipe.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            for (Plate plate : plateRep.findAll()) {
                for (Recipe recipe : listRecipe) {
                    if (recipe.getPlate().getId() == plate.getId()) {
                        results.add(plate);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is any less tedious way to do this, without invoking multiple for loops. One of my alternatives is using @Query and directly joining the tables to form a MySql query, but it's  just as tedious.

Comment: `but it's just as tedious` ... if you're referring to the effort involved in coding both versions, you might be right.  From the performance point of view, joining the tables and running a single query will _massively_ outperform what you are currently doing.

Comment: I know, which is why I'm asking for an alternative. It's to avoid scenarios where the database is too large and I don't want to join, let's say, 7 tables at once.